# Blurred Box like in the Blizzard Website

Tags: css

Already some time ago I saw, that the background of the navigation on Blizzard's website (www.blizzard.com) is somehow "blurred". Not in the sense of the normal Blur Filter in CSS, as the border of this box itself is not blurred. 
In my current project, I would like to implement this effect, but since I don't understand the source code of Blizzard at all, I would be very happy if someone could explain how all of that works.

oh and btw.. I want to blur the 2 transparent boxes in this fiddle:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
}
body {
  background-image: url("https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/1914112/images/o-PARIS-facebook.jpg");
}
#costumNavigationBar {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 300;
 width: 100%;
  
}
#costumTopPanel {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 0px;
 background-color: #0c0c0c;
 z-index: 200;a
}
#costumTopPanelContent {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
#costumTopPanelContentLeft {
 color: #FFF;
}
#costumTopPanelContentRight {
 color: #FFF;
}


#costumMainMenu {
  background-color: rgba(12,12,12,0.5);
 padding: 25px 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#costumMainMenuContent {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.pageHeaderLogoLarge {
 position: absolute;
 left: 40.3%;
 top: 29%;
}
#costumLogoBackground {
 background: url('http://atlas.irs-media.de/images/atlasgamingbilder/headerBG.svg') no-repeat; 
 height: 120px;
 width: 530px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#pageHeaderPanel {
 position: relative; 
}

#costumMainMenuContentLeft {
 color: #FFF; 
}
#costumMainMenuContentRight {
 color: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<div id="costumNavigationBar"> 
 <div id="costumTopPanel">
  <div class="layoutBoundary">
   <div id="costumTopPanelContent">
    <div id="costumTopPanelContentLeft">
     Icons
    </div>
    <div id="costumTopPanelContentRight">
     Login
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="costumMainMenu">
  <div class="layoutBoundary">
   <div id="costumMainMenuContent">
    <div id="costumMainMenuContentLeft">
     Menu Left
    </div>
    <div id="costumMainMenuContentMid">
     Logo
    </div>
    <div id="costumMainMenuContentRight">
     Menu Right
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="costumLogoBackground"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're specifically asking how Blizzard is accomplishing this, the answer is there's no CSS involved in the blur. Instead, they've baked a blur directly into the top 60px of each image file in the desktop carousel.

Here's one of the slides so you can see:
https://bnetcmsus-a.akamaihd.net/cms/gallery/pt/PTRQ0098SJYL1509731760219.jpg

With that said, here's one way you could achieve a blurred box with a solid border using the [`::before` or `::after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before), the blur [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) property and [`background-attachment: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/1914112/images/o-PARIS-facebook.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
}

.blur-box {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  margin: 1em;
  height: 50vw;
  width: 50vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blur-box::before {
  background-image: url("https://s-i.huffpost.com/gen/1914112/images/o-PARIS-facebook.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  top: -10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(.5em);
  filter: blur(.5em);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-box"></div>
```